# How to select the result from data success of ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

These are my code:

```
$("#promo_form").submit(function(stay){
    $.ajax ({
        type: "post",
        url: "<?=base_url()?>promo/code_validate",
        data: $("#promo_form").serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            $("#myModalLabel").html(data);
        }
    });
    stay.preventDefault();
});
```

And the success data result below:

> $result1 = "code is invalid";
>
> $result2  = "promo unavailable";

How can I select these and retrieve it?

This is what I did below but now working.

```
$("#myModalLabel").html(data->result1);
```

Comment: What exactly is your php script *returning*? You show us the variables but no echo statement.

Comment: if i echo "code is invalid"; and $("#myModalLabel").html(data);     the result is = code is invalid;

Comment: If you are just echoing  that text, try adding `dataType:"text",` to your ajax option object, what you have, `$("#myModalLabel").html(data);`, should work as is though.

Comment: but how could i select what i want to retrieve? want i need sir is retrive is by something like these. $("#modal-1").html(data.result1); & $("#modal-2").html(data.result2);

Comment: I added an answer to demonstrate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this

**Function controller**

```
function code_validate()
{
    echo json_encode(array('result1'=>'Code is invalid',
                           'result2'=>'Promo not available');
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#promo_form").submit(function(stay){
    $.ajax ({
        type: "post",
        url: "<?=base_url()?>promo/code_validate",
        data: $("#promo_form").serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            var mydata = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(mydata.result1);
            console.log(mydata.result1);
        }
    });
    stay.preventDefault();
});
```

You must return it as JSON.

**Goodluck meyt**

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript uses dot syntax for accessing object properties, so...

```
$("#myModalLabel").html(data.result1);
```

I'll also add that you want to make sure the page at `promo/code_validate` prints out a [JSON](http://www.json.org/) response, as that is how `data` will become an object (`$.ajax` is intelligent about how to parse the server's response, see the link below). So your `code_validate` page might look something like this:

```
{
    "result1": "code is invalid",
    "result2": "promo unavailable"
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Vincent, add the dataType paramater to your ajax call, setting it to 'json'.  Then just parse the response to convert it to an object so that you can access the variables easily, e.g.

```
in AJAX call:
dataType: "json"

in success function:
var obj = jquery.parseJSON(data);
console.log(obj);//echo the object to the console
console.log(obj.result1);//echo the result1 property only, for example
```

Comment: You as well as the OP are mixing php and javascript syntax

Comment: type: "post",
   url: "<?=base_url()?>promo/code_validate",
   data: $("#promo_form").serialize(),
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data){
    var obj = jquery.parseJSON(data);
    console.log(obj);//echo the object to the console
    console.log(obj.result1);//echo the result1 property only, for example
   }

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do what you want is create a php associative array of your values then json encode the array and echo the resulting string like this:

```
$response = ["result1"=>"code is invalid", "result2"=>"promo unavailable"];
echo json_encode($response);
```

Then on the client side, access them like this

```
$("#promo_form").submit(function(stay){
    $.ajax ({
        type: "post",
        url: "<?=base_url()?>promo/code_validate",
        data: $("#promo_form").serialize(),
        success: function(data){
           $("#modal-1").html(data.result1); 
           $("#modal-2").html(data.result2);
        }
    });
    stay.preventDefault();
});
```